# What is the shell environment? Using an API

Tags: ruby, api

I'm following an API ruby tutorial and for one step using the Lastfm api, it says to do this.

```
And we should add some setup to our spec_helper.rb:

LastRubyFm.api_key = ENV['last_fm_api_key']

We use the shell environment as a way to access the last fm api key. The ENV has looks at the      
collection of our shell's environment variables. In order to use this functionality it will be   
necessary for you to execute the following in your shell:

export last_fm_api_key='<YOUR API KEY>'


This keeps our credentials secure so that they are not committed into source control. You will   
have  to run this every time you use this library or run tests with it, so let's set up a .env 
file. This adheres to a popular principal that is part of the Twelve factor app.

export last_fm_api_key='<YOUR API KEY>'

Now, every time you run the suite on this library, you can run source .env loading this   
 environment variable every time.
```

First of all is the .env file something that goes in a directory. Second what exactly goes into the .env file? Is it the export piece of information.

I'm confused because this tutorial covers creating an API in a wrapper. How would I get a users credentials for their API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of what they're trying to get to is keeping configuration variables out of your repository, thus more secure.  However, I agree that the documentation is a bit confusing.

Basically, you can store variables in your environment as variables (e.g. bash variables, if you're using bash as your shell).  A good description of how this works and why it's useful is in [Heroku's config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) documentation.

Assuming you use the bash shell, you would add a line to your `~/.bashrc` file such as:

`export last_fm_api_key='<YOUR API KEY>'`

After doing this, restart your shell.  You'll notice if you type `last_fm_api_key` in your shell, your API key is returned.  The environment is available in your app via the `ENV` constant.

Specifically with the `.env` file, I believe they are referring to the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem.  Personally, I prefer the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro), but whatever fits your needs is what you should use.  [RailsApps](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) has some good documentation, including alternatives on this.